# URL rewriting htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite some of my urls, but still getting errors messages.
My website is PHP developed. I managed to have all dynamic urls looks static. but for one category, I'm not able to find the right condition and rule to apply.

Here is the type of urls I want to rewrite (It's dynamic):

```
mywebsite.com/details/id/34556 (mywebsite.com/details/id/34556/vehicle-in england-to-rent)
mywebsite.com/details/id/2312 (mywebsite.com/details/id/2312/new-car-london)
```

I'd like to have it like that:

```
mywebsite.com/vehicle/id/34556 (mywebsite.com/details/id/34556/vehicle-in england-to-rent)
mywebsite.com/vehicle/id/2312 (mywebsite.com/details/id/2312/new-car-london)
```

I've included the condition on my htaccess file, but no result so far.
Here is the code I've used:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/details/id/([0-9]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^/vehicle/id/([0-9]+)$ [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I'm finally able to see the change needed in my web browser but editing the code like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?details/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /vehicle/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/?details/(.*)$ /vehicle/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The url in the browser appears now as expected. However, the webpage is a 404 error page. I have the desired url, but not the page. is there anyway to change the condition to make it work?

Comment: I'm not a big fan of Apache's rewrite rules, but doesn't `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/details/id/([0-9]+)$` mean you only apply further rules if that condition is met? Then the rule below won't trigger because it doesn't match the condition.

Comment: @ Camil Staps Yes you're right. But having the rule including the condition like that doesn't work either:  "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /vehicle/%1 [R=301,L]".
I'm also not a big fan of Apache's rewrite rules, but it seems to be the easier way as I don't really want to rewrite the codes inside.

Comment: For regex capture groups you should use `$1`, not `%1`.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/vehicle/id/([0-9]+)$ [R=301,NE,L]` this won't do anything except perhaps error out. You need to state where you are re-writing to. `RewriteRule ^/vehicle/id/([0-9]+)$ /some/other/url [R=301,NE,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
# Remove the line: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/details/id/([0-9]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^details/id/([0-9]+)$ /vehicle/id/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

The first part is what is being tested (that is, the regular expression), and the second part is where it should be redirected to when matched.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with this: [code] (RewriteRule ^/?details/(.*)$ /vehicle/$1 [R=301,L])

It worked on the browser, unfortunately, I'm getting a 404 error page as output

Comment: That is not the rule I gave in my answer. I have, however, updated it to remove the leading slash. Please use my rule as it is shown (it should be one of your first rules). If you are getting a 404 error, where is that error coming from? Is your PHP application throwing the error, or is Apache throwing it?

Comment: yes, I tried your code too. the url is changing, but the output is just a missing page. Page doesn't exist... May be it should not be rewritten here. It's like a simple redirection to a new url instead of rewrite the url.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're not making much sense. Is the error coming from your script or from Apache? It must be coming from your app as you have passed `(.*)` to `index.php`. As the above answers your question, please mark it as accepted and open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late return.
After checking the server for weeks, I finally found what was missing.
The rewriteRule you've provided was almost perfect. But the only issue was that the htaccess was redirecting the query to a new url, but as I haven't created the new page, the output result was a 404 error. 
So, the make things right, I had to create a new php file (using the same code as the previous) and rename it differently (vehicle). The I apply the htaccess redirection with the code provided above.
It works perfectly.
Thanks!!